# html/javascript adding script to my page

Tags: javascript, html

[SOLVED]

i'm trying to make it so that when i click on cuboidCalc
it replaces outputOne with with the code in the cuboidCalc function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>volume only</p>
<input type="button" onclick="cuboidCalc()"> cuboidCalc <br>
<input type="button" onclick="cylinderCalc()"> cylinderCalc <br>
<input type="button" onclick="triPrismCalc()"> triPrismCalc <br>

<p id="outputOne"></p>

<p id="outputTwo"></p>

<script>
function cuboidCalc() {
    document.getElementById("outputOne").innerHTML = "hight: <input type="number" id="hight" value="">";

}
function cylinderCalc() {

}
function triPrismCalc() {

}
</script>
```

Comment: was is the result? right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your double quotes (`"..."`) as you use them to enclose and to specify attribute values inside the function. Try replacing the enclosing or inner double quotes with single quotes like this:

```
function cuboidCalc() {
    document.getElementById("outputOne").innerHTML = 'hight: <input type="number" id="hight" value="">';
}
```

*Edit: to explain this better, the double quote inside the string statement will make the statement stop, therefore anything after it will be understood as code, and thus will make no sense. This is why you have to alter the quotations, so one is understood as enclosing the entire statement, while the others can be used inside it to specify attribute values. If you need even more quotation, use the backslash (`\`) escape character, eg. `statement = '<input onClick="foo(\'bar\')">'`.*

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bfn3ujwk/).

Answer (score 0):

Just change your quotations I think:

```
function cuboidCalc() {
    document.getElementById("outputOne").innerHTML = "hight: <input type='number' id='hight' value=''>";

}
```

I also changed the input to a `<button>` if that makes any difference